# How can I view all (most recent) tweets directed at a particular user?

Tags: twitter

There is a writer who recently wrote an article for Slate. People are responding to him on Twitter. But I don't know how to see all their tweets.

- The Twitter user is: https://twitter.com/alienvsrobbins
- Here is an example of a  tweet directed at that user: https://twitter.com/cejarvis/status/486598974535524352

When I search Twitter for the username, I get no recent results.

Comment: The former. I get only these two old messages: http://i.imgur.com/EyZEaYW.png

Comment: @pnuts I should add that this is what I get even in another browser, logged out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all tweets directed to a particular user, use the `to:` operator.

```
to:alienvsrobbins
```

If you want the direct URL, the above creates: https://twitter.com/search?q=to%3Aalienvsrobbins

(More at [Twitter Help](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577-using-advanced-search))